# How can I solve for $x$ in this equation?

Tags: problem-solving

I have this equation, but I don't know how can I isolate the $x$ laying inside the cosine function.

$$x=\cos\left(\frac{4\pi x+2T\phi}{2Tr}\right)\cdot r$$

What are the best steps to pass around this issue?

Comment: You can't solve for $x$ algebraically, but you can solve for it numerically for general $T,\phi,r$.

Comment: Could you explain further? Why isn´t possible for x? I already know the values for $T, \phi , r$. Will these help me to find the real value of x?

Comment: Remember that $x=\cos(x)$ does not show any analytical solution.

Comment: That´s right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe that an analytical solution is difficult to find manually, you can get the solutions using a graphing software with those values.

For example, in **Desmos** (https://www.desmos.com/calculator), *inputting the 2 functions (the left hand side and the right hand side of the equation respectively) along with $T=\phi=r=2$, I get the solution: $x=0.275$.*

Comment: That software is awesome.